# gdb coredump analysis failure

Tags: gdb, coredump

(gdb) shared info -> this shows that all the shared lib syms have been read
But still back trace bt shows that 'No symbol table info available' for any of the functions.

Can someone throw some light on what the issue could be ? How can I resolve this and get a meaningful trace back?

Answer (score 2):

That column in the `info shared` output is perennially confusing.  It doesn't mean that there actually is debug info -- it just means that gdb tried to read it.  This information isn't actually all that useful to ordinary users.

It's surprisingly hard to find out if you actually have debug info.  One way to do it is to use `readelf -WS` on your various files and look for the relevant debug sections.  This will tell you if it exists.

However!  Even this isn't enough.  Maybe a section is missing (it is unlikely unless you have been mucking around with the files).  Or maybe gdb rejected some part of the debug info (also reasonably unlikely).

Another possibility is that you have separated the debug info from the libraries.  This is typical in distros.  In this case you have to make sure to install the debug info packages -- in Fedora you can do this with `debuginfo-install`; presumably there are similar methods on other distros.

In the separate debug info case you have to be sure to install exactly the same versions of the files that were used by the process that made the core.  This can be difficult.  Sometimes it can be done by inspecting the build ids, but this isn't always possible, as distros frequently purge out-of-date versions of the files.

If the libraries in question are your libraries, then you have to recompile them with `-g` and then try to recreate the core.  There's really no reliable way to generate the necessary debug info after the fact.

If the core was created on some other machine, you can try to find those files and install them locally.  You can install them pretty much anywhere and use the `set sysroot` feature to tell gdb how to find them.